# How to capture and style the top checkbox in a 2 level list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is doing my head in.  I have a 2-level list that functions nicely with some jQuery.  I want to capture the top checkbox ('Master checkbox') to style it in CSS and hover a border around it, but I can't seem to access it.  Wrapping a label around the input tag messses up my jQuery and doesn't seem to help anyway.
Any ideas anyone on what I'm doing wrong?  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6890337d/)

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
  $(this).next().find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
  $(this).parents('ul').prev('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', function() {
    return $(this).next().find(':checked').length;
  });
});
```

```css
.treeBOXClass {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 540px;
  height: 250px;
  font-family: "Verdana", Arial, serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: white;
}
.treeBOXClass ul li {
  color: blue;
  margin: 7px 0px 4px 12px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.myFlexbox {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.my_RH_Text {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="treeBOXClass">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="mastercheckbox" value="yes" />Master checkbox
    <ul>
      <label for="HS1">
        <div class="myFlexbox">
          <li><input type="checkbox" id="HS1" value="one" />HS1</li>
          <div class="my_RH_Text">
            This is text that I have put in the first box as an example
          </div>
        </div>
      </label>
      <label for="HS2">
        <div class="myFlexbox">
          <li><input type="checkbox" id="HS2" value="one" />HS2</li>
          <div class="my_RH_Text">
            This is text that I have put in the second box as an example
          </div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </ul>
  </li><br>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have a big problem with your HTML here - it's invalid. You cannot have any element other than an `<li>` as the child of the `<ul>`

Comment: Maybe this could help you https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap a label around the input element and move the id to it.

Then tweak the jquery so instead of targeting the sibling, it has to go to the parent THEN the sibling.

Proof of concept: I've added a red border around the master checkbox.

PS: Also wrapped the `ul` children in `li` tags for valid html.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().next().find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
  $(this).parents('ul').prev().find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', function() {
    return $(this).parent().next().find(':checked').length;
  });
});
```

```css
#mastercheckbox {
  border:1px solid red;
}
.treeBOXClass {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 540px;
  height: 250px;
  font-family: "Verdana", Arial, serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: white;
}
.treeBOXClass ul li {
  color: blue;
  margin: 7px 0px 4px 12px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.myFlexbox {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.my_RH_Text {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="treeBOXClass">
  <li>
    <label id="mastercheckbox"><input type="checkbox" value="yes" />Master checkbox</label>
    <ul>
      <li>
      <label for="HS1">
        <div class="myFlexbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="HS1" value="one" />HS1
          <div class="my_RH_Text">
            This is text that I have put in the first box as an example
          </div>
        </div>
      </label>
        </li>
      <li>
      <label for="HS2">
        <div class="myFlexbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="HS2" value="one" />HS2
          <div class="my_RH_Text">
            This is text that I have put in the second box as an example
          </div>
        </div>
      </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </li><br>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thats great @Richard Parnaby-King, thanks for your clear explanation. But on the other hand I've already spent the last hour trying to get the 2nd level checkbox and associated text back inside its flexbox (with blue border), as it was originally.  Do you know how?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: That's it!  Your help much appreciated.